# FileSystemDirectoryHandle - Open a File in Directory (Permissions Granted)

Tags: javascript, html

I am using HTML 5 File System API technology to select a directory ([showDirectoryPicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showDirectoryPicker)) and request/grant access to the entire directory ([FileSystemDirectoryHandle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryHandle)) using the browser.

I am now able to read files from that directory and write to it as well, without any issues.

Question though - I know browser security is very strict, but since there is already local access granted to that entire directory - is there any way I execute something that resides also in that folder? Like a batch script, or an exe or a jar file. It contains some scripts that need to be ran (user triggered by a click of a button)?

Or.. Is there any way to execute something that is part of the html bundle (resides at the same directory as the .html file).

By the way this is for a static site (file://).

Also, preferably, would like to keep it this way - the executable that is to be ran actually is some sort of a backend server (which calls NodeJS native commands) which will be used by other applications as well. So the static html page will be communicating with this little 'server'. The reason why I want this auto-executed is I want to make it a more seamless experience for the user. It would be quite cumbersome to always click 2 things when running the app ((1) the static html page and (2) the server).

Thanks!

Comment: No, browsers don't have execute access, your users would have to execute the file.   But have you considered making an electron app, as this is basically a browser & node glued together and you can then do much more, like a native app.   https://www.electronjs.org/

Comment: Thank you. Electron app would be our backup in case there's really no way around it, but really strongly prefer to just have it as a static page (for portability/lightweight)..

Comment: If you wanted something more lightweight than electron, There is -> https://tauri.app/  & https://neutralino.js.org/  Not used either of them, but look promising, eg. It's possible to have apps of 0.5mb.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly wrote that browser security is sufficiently high, and as a developer, you have no documented and available option to run any executable through the browser.

In case you are developing a solution that needs to work with a local file/operating system and use the browser as a means to interact with the user (GUI), the only option available is to write a backend service that also runs locally, and that will run the executable on request from the browser.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Just want to confirm - when you say backend service, are you referring to a server/localhost? Any suggestions on how this can be done totally offline?

Comment: For example, the app will be available at http://localhost:8080/.

The application gives you a page from this address to browse the local filesystem and select a file. Once you have the file address, you can pass it to your application's API, which will, in turn, run the executable file. For example, suppose the file you want to run is "file://c:/temp/executable.bat". Then, you can write a request handler at "/api/exec" (the full address is http://localhost:8080/api/exec" where you send the executable address with the post request, and the application will try to run it.

Comment: In addition, as correctly suggested in the comments to the thread - using tools to create hybrid applications with built-in node.js - can also solve your problem.

Comment: I have added some notes just now - was hoping to keep the structure as it is. "Preferably, would like to keep it this way - the executable that is to be ran actually is some sort of a backend server (which calls NodeJS native commands) which will be used by other applications as well. So the static html page will be communicating with this little 'server'. The reason why I want this auto-executed is I want to make it a more seamless experience for the user. It would be quite cumbersome to always click 2 things when running the app ((1) the static html page and (2) the server)."